# How to update "comodel_name" attribute of inheriting model's Many2one fields in Odoo?

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I would like to update

```
address_id = fields.Many2one ( comodel_name = 'res.partner' )
```

to the following:

```
address_id = fields.Many2one ( comodel_name = 'res.company' )
```

But it will raise the Following error:

```
insert or update on table "hr_employee" violates foreign key constraint "hr_employee_address_id_fkey"
```

Comment: I think you should make all values to null first if they are not

Comment: Can you just make a new field instead? `company_address_id` = fields.Many2one('res.company')`

Comment: Thanks you all. I see that the way EasyOdoo mentioned work. The problem is the legacy database data have some invalid value against 'res.company'. I remove or reset that data and everything is ok now. travisw's solution is an easy way to follow but it seems like not make sense in the inheritance context, it's only way if the data is in production. For now I prefer the first one.

Comment: Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example